# The content on my Tumblr theme completely disappears

Tags: html, css, tumblr

For some reason the content on my Tumblr theme doesn't show up, which is very frustrating. Sometimes it will show for a split second and then vanish. I have NO idea what could be causing this. I can't post the entire theme code in here, since I don't know where the error could be, so I've put the layout [code into Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NmyLh8Qv).

[Here is the link](http://arthiaravind.tumblr.com) to the Tumblr itself.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as the theme looks perfect when it chooses to show up. :/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `bottom: 1%;` from the `body` tag.

Comment: Remove the position: relative from your html tag as well.  I think those two combined will give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: You'll want to add position: inherit; since it doesn't look like you're specifying that in your stylesheet.